# Android Button to show downloaded files

Tags: android, button, download

Here's my scenario

1. User downloads a file from my app
2. User presses the menu button to go to the downloaded files located in SD Card

Please show me how to implement a button to link to SD CARD location

below are my codes.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/downloaded/stuffs");
dir.mkdirs();

File file = new File(dir, fileName);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: You want a Button, that when clicked, lists the files on the SDCard?

Comment: Thanks Spidy for your reply. I just want a simple button link to my downloaded files in my SD location. Please reply .  Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button handler

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, FileList.class);
    startActivity(intent);

 }
});
```

And to show all files in that directory define class FileList like this

```
public class FileList extends ListActivity 
{
    private File file;
    private List<String> myList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myList = new ArrayList<String>();   

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/downloaded/stuffs");

        File list[] = dir.listFiles();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);